# JSON are not show in mobile app using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, mobile

This data are show in the web browser  but not in the  mobile app

i already check the internet connection in mobile but cant't get it any answer

**This is my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
function customersController($scope,$http) {
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php")
  .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**But my mobile is show me this output ->**

```
  {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
```

but my web browser show me the correct answer

```
Alfreds Futterkiste, Germany
Berglunds snabbköp, Sweden
Centro comercial Moctezuma, Mexico
Ernst Handel, Austria
FISSA Fabrica Inter. Salchichas S.A., Spain
Galería del gastrónomo, Spain
Island Trading, UK
Königlich Essen, Germany
Laughing Bacchus Wine Cellars, Canada
Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti, Italy
North/South, UK
Paris spécialités, France
Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery, USA
Simons bistro, Denmark
The Big Cheese, USA
Vaffeljernet, Denmark
Wolski Zajazd, Poland
```

In this case what can i do for mobile app

Comment: appears that either angular isn't being bootstrapped, or you have errors being thrown that are blocking the dom rendering

Comment: dom rendering mean's..???

Comment: means angular dynamically updating the html in page. DOM = Document Object Model

Comment: my data are show in the html browser but when i load the apk in my phone then data are not what can i do in this case..??? please Mr. charlietfl sir can right this code for me and what is the solution for this  i am  beginner in this

Comment: I can't do anything...you need to do some troubleshooting to look for errors. I have no way to inspect for those

Comment: where can set this solution....??? and where can i see this error in my code please help me out

Comment: in developer debugging tools

Comment: developer debugging tools is don't send me any error... sir can you give me the sample code of any project for this solution

Comment: are files all loading?

Comment: Yes all files loading

Comment: throw an alert in and see what happens.

Comment: function Hello($scope, $http) { alert("dddddddddddd");
    $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting').

        success(function(data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
} alert are not show

Comment: well there is no way that all these things are accurate then. Either files aren't loading, or errors are thrown

Comment: can you send me the any link of this RestFull api and this type of any project please solution of this case

Comment: Working fine for me on mobile also http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/Lxo466pL

Comment: you will just have to start learning about troubleshooting by researching methods and tools on the web. I can't teach you in comment blocks here especially when there are some sort of errors being generated that you don't know how to look for on your device. Is your device compatible with angular? I don't need an answer to that ... just something else you need to look into

Comment: Then what can i do for this

Comment: Mr. wiz kid this working in my PC but not working in my mobile

Comment: https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=5267 refer this link.